# Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotFound in Tags#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I stored the image name in DB. I put all my images in *app/assets/images* folder. I print all the images using rails image_tag. But it shows AssetNotFound Error. I also tried some other ways to print the images in browser. I used following methods.

`<%= image_tag tag.img %>

app/assets/images/`

I tried these all ways. But the problem is not solved. If I put the name directly, it will print the image. 

For example

    
prints the image. But the same image name is present in the `tag.img`. If I used

It will through the **AssetNotFound Error** and it shows *The asset "hash_tag.jpg" is not present in the asset pipeline is not present*

Please clear my problem.

Comment: It also error for `development`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As referred here in the [image_tag documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag) if you passed

```
image_tag(tag.img)
```

It will reproduce:

```
<img src="/assets/[YOUR TAG IMG]" />
```

So I believe that yours should look like this:

```
image_tag("/images/#{tag.img}")
```